# ColdFusion Arrays, retain values

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, retain, dynamic-arrays

I have one form with a table and an "ADD ITEMS" button.  On clicking "ADD ITEMS", a 2nd form is opened where the user can add details. On clicking "Submit" on the 2nd Page, the details should get added as a new row in the table in the first screen.
I am using an array and struct to add/append in the array .

Every time a user tries to add a new row, I'm creating a new struct in the existing array(on page 1) and try to display the array on the first page.

```
<cfset arrayRequisition[k] = StructNew() />     
<cfset arrayRequisition[k].Part_Nbr = #Variables.ReqDescription# />     
<cfset arrayRequisition[k].Description = #Variables.EQT_DESCRIPTION# />     
<cfset arrayRequisition[k].Quantity = #Variables.RQT_QUANTITY# />   
<cfset arrayRequisition[k].Status = "pending" />    
<cfset arrayRequisition[k].Line_No = #i# />
```

Here `K` is the count of rows added and incremented every time. However I am getting the error when I'm doing so:

> "Array field 1 not found".

When I fix that, the table displays only the last row.

```
<cfoutput>
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Part_Nbr&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Description&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Quantity&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Status&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Line_No</td>
  </tr> 
  <cfdump var="#i#">
  <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(arrayRequisition)#" index="j">
  <cfdump var="#arrayLen(arrayRequisition)#">
  <tr>
   <td>#arrayRequisition[j].Part_Nbr#</td>
   <td>#arrayRequisition[j].Description#</td>
   <td>#arrayRequisition[j].Quantity#</td>
   <td>#arrayRequisition[j].Status#</td>
   <td style="text-align:right;">#arrayRequisition[j].Line_No#</td>
 </tr>
 </cfloop>
 </table>
 </cfoutput>
```

From what I understand, during the transition between the two pages, my previous struct data /array data gets lost. How can I retain the values of my array in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two different ColdFusion templates (.cfm files).  If that is the case then you need to understand that the variables you are using in your ColdFusion templates are only available during that browser request.  Once the ColdFusion templates run and the response is sent back to the user those variables are "lost".  Here is a page that gives an overview of the life cycle in ColdFusion applications: [Elements of a ColdFusion application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0b63c-7fd5.html).

In order to persist the values for subsequent requests you could (this is not an all inclusive list):

- Pass ALL of the values with each form submission
- Store your variables in a persistent scope, like the `session`
- Use a database to store the values

Then depending on which option you choose, your ColdFusion templates will need to be changed to store the values in the persistent place (your second template) and read the existing values from the persistent place (your first template).

It would also be possible to rewrite the entire process to make use of AJAX calls from a single ColdFusion template. Where the AJAX functions would call on a new ColdFusion CFC that would need to be written that controls the updating and retrieving of the variable values. I believe this option would be a more extensive rewrite for you however.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that `arrayRequisition` is indeed an array. By using the syntax you show in the first example, CF would create a structure, not an array. Doing `varName[x] = someVar` will actually give you a structure with a key of the value of the variable `x`

To create an array you would need to create a struct that contains the keys `Part_nbr`, `Description`, etc and then call `arrayAppend( arrayRequisition, newStruct)`